# The Texture on a mesh moves in animation

Tags: animation, mesh, texturing, uv

I am making an animation with two texts converted to mesh that have wooden textures.  When I animate this, the textures on both move for some reason.  Even stranger, I have two other meshes, a cube and a floor plane, whose textures don't move.  Anyone have any ideas?  Here is a link to the animation for reference:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5WX5WPaU3pHUndFN3dVTVdrbkE&authuser=0

Comment: Doesn't look like the textures move at all. It looks like you reflection enabled. Would it be possible for you to post the .blend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have reflectivity turned on. **Uncheck** this box:

[image: Uncheck mirror.]

---

If using Cycles renderer, make sure you're using a Diffuse texture instead of a Glossy one:

[image]

Comment: I'm using Cycles Render, so I didn't have that option, but I did notice that I used the Glossy option under the Surface tab and that must have been it.

Comment: @AidenMcMinimy Ah, okay.